# React - Change value of a imported component

Tags: reactjs

I have a `Button.js` component and I am using it on multiple locations on my app. How can I add the button value such as `<button>hello world</button>` when I am importing it on my `Dashboard.js` component?

**Button.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './Button.css'

class Button extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button></button>
      );
    }
  }
  
  export default Button;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import Button from "../Button/Button";
import SearchBox from "../SearchBox/SearchBox";
import "./Dashboard.css";
import fire from "../../fire";
import UserList from "./UserList";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Button/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a value to **Button** component in two ways

```
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Button>Hello world</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button>{this.props.children}</button>
      );
    }
  }
```

or

```
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Button value="hello world"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button>{this.props.value}</button>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the value in as a prop.

In the Dashboard component:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Button value="hello world"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the button component:

```
class Button extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button>{this.props.value}</button>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

send text via props

**Button.js**

```
class Button extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button>{this.props.text}</button>
      );
    }
  }
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Button text={'Here is your custom text'}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}


class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button>
          hello world
      </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```